# (JavaFX) Unable to use controls when binding the textProperty()?

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I'm just getting started in learning property binding.  I have my controls set and the properties bound here (code abbreviated):

```
@FXML
    private TextField txtOldPremium;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNewPremium;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtProratedChange;

    private SimpleBooleanProperty quoteOnly = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private SimpleBooleanProperty reviewedBilling = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty oldPremium = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty newPremium = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty proratedChange = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty additionalInformation = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        // Bind the vehicle data to the tableview
        colEffectiveDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vehicle, String>("effectiveDateString"));
        colDescription.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vehicle, String>("description"));
        colVIN.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vehicle, String>("vin"));
        colAction.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Vehicle, String>("action"));

        // Setup data binding to controls
        chkQuoteOnly.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(quoteOnly);
        chkReviewedBilling.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(reviewedBilling);
        txtOldPremium.textProperty().bindBidirectional(oldPremium);
        txtNewPremium.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newPremium);
    }

    @Override
    public String getComments() {
        StringBuilder comments = new StringBuilder();

        if (!txtOldPremium.getText().isEmpty() && !txtNewPremium.getText().isEmpty()) {

        } else {

            }
        }
        if (!txtProratedChange.getText().isEmpty()) {

        }
```

I am getting a NullPointerException at `if (!txtOldPremium.getText().isEmpty() && !txtNewPremium.getText().isEmpty()) {`.  I am assuming I am doing something radically wrong with implementing the bindings.  The TextFields themselves are currently empty.

Basically, I just want the `TextField` and the `oldPremium` String to always remain in sync with eachother.  But I still need to be able to do processing on the text `TextField`.  I do have several other types of controls (`CheckBox`, `ComboBox`, etc) that I want to have sync with the underlying data.

Comment: What is actually null?

Comment: It turns out, the `txtOldPremium.getText()` is null if no text is entered into it..  I'm curious why that null now that I've bound the property, though.  Prior to binding, `txtOldPremium.getText().isEmpty()` would just return true.  (`txtOldPremium` is reference to a `TextField`)

Comment: Well presumably `oldPremium`, whatever that is, contains `null` when you do the binding.

Comment: I am binding them within the `initialize()` method of my FXML controller.  Is that not the right place to do so?

Comment: What does that have to do with it? Obviously, `oldPremium.getValue()` is returning `null` at the time you execute `bindBidirectional(...)`, so when you do the binding it sets the text of the text field to `null`. You haven't shown any code showing how, when, or where you initialize `oldPremium`, or even what it is.

Comment: I've edited my question to show more of the relevant code.

Comment: I understand the values are null; the Exception makes that pretty clear.  I guess my overall question is why are they null?  If it is null when the binding was done, how would I avoid that?  Do I need to initialize all the values to "" first and then bind them?

Comment: They're null because you didn't initialize them to anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the text properties of the text fields to `StringProperty` instances that have been created without an initial value. So, for example, when you do

```
private SimpleStringProperty oldPremium = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

you create `oldPremium` without an actual value. So `oldPremium.getValue()` will return `null`.

So then when you do

```
txtOldPremium.textProperty().bindBidirectional(oldPremium);
```

you synchronize the state of the two properties (`txtOldPremium.textProperty()` and `oldPremium`), which involves copying the value of `oldPremium` (which is `null`) into `txtOldPremium.textProperty()`.

So just initialize the properties to hold an empty string, instead of null:

```
private SimpleStringProperty oldPremium = new SimpleStringProperty("");
```

etc.

Also, though, note that in this particular example you can achieve the same thing without duplicating all the properties. I.e. you can just do

```
private StringProperty oldPremium ;

// ...

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    // ...

    oldPremium = txtOldPremium.textProperty();

    // ...

}
```

You can still define property accessor methods

```
public StringProperty oldPremiumProperty() {
    return oldPremium ;
}

public final String getOldPremium() {
    return oldPremiumProperty().get();
}

public final void setOldPremium(String oldPremium) {
    oldPremiumProperty().set(oldPremium);
}
```

as you presumably already have, and it will have exactly the same effect, but with less overhead.

Bidirectional bindings are really most useful for synchronizing properties that belong to two different objects (e.g. properties belonging to different controllers, or to a controller and a model). Maybe your question reduced the code to demonstrate the problem, but I thought I would point this out for other users.

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick.  I was worried doing so would overwrite the data already in those text fields, but that did not happen.

Comment: @Zephyr Yeah but see update. I don't see the point of the code you have.

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm doing things in a very inefficient manner; I'm still very new to Java.  I wanted to bind the properties to avoid the need to manually save any changes to the TextField back to the `oldPremium` property; calling the `getOldPremium()' method would not get any changes made to the TextField itself.

Comment: In the code modification I made, `getOldPremium()` or `oldPremiumProperty().get()` will always have the value displayed in the text field, but without instantiating a whole new property object. Similarly, calling `setOldPremium(...)` or `oldPremiumProperty().set(...)` will automatically update the text field. (You can even get rid of the reference `oldPremium`, and just have `oldPremiumProperty()` return `txtOldPremium.textProperty()` directly.)

Comment: I do like the simplicity of `oldPremium = txtOldPremium.textProperty()`, but I do need the `TextField` to update automatically when `oldPremium` changes. For my case, I have the FXML loading when the `oldPremium` and other values are already initialized with data that I want populated in the controls. Would that be a situation where the bidirectional binding would be necessary?